# Particle System - Towel render

Tags: particles

I want to render towel in blender using hair particle.
I have selected object in Particle Render instead of path, but want same color on particle as on towel. Issue is that particle-(object) is using different shader. Is there any way to render particle object in same way as path gets render. Hope attached image will clear what i am asking for.
thanks[image]